# How to create unittests for python prompt toolkit?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to create unittests for my command line interface
build with the Python `prompt-toolkit` (https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit).

- **How can I emulate user interaction with the prompt-toolkit?**
- **Is there a best practice for these unittests?**

Example Code:

```
from os import path
from prompt_toolkit import prompt

def csv():
    csv_path = prompt('\nselect csv> ')
    full_path = path.abspath(csv_path)
    return full_path
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could [mock](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock) the prompt calls.

**app_file**

```
from prompt_toolkit import prompt

def word():
    result = prompt('type a word')
    return result
```

**test_app_file**

```
import unittest
from app import word
from mock import patch

class TestAnswer(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_yes(self):
        with patch('app.prompt', return_value='Python') as prompt:
            self.assertEqual(word(), 'Python')
            prompt.assert_called_once_with('type a word')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Just an attention to the point you should mock the prompt from the **app.py**, not from **prompt_toolkit**, because you want to intercept the call from the file.

According with the [docstring module](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit/blob/master/prompt_toolkit/shortcuts.py#L4-L7):

> If you are using this library for retrieving some input from the user (as a
>   pure Python replacement for GNU readline), probably for 90% of the use cases,
>   the :func:`.prompt` function is all you need.

And as [method docstring](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit/blob/master/prompt_toolkit/shortcuts.py#L512-L515) says:

> Get input from the user and return it.
>       This is a wrapper around a lot of `prompt_toolkit` functionality and can be a replacement for `raw_input`. (or GNU readline.)

Following the [Getting started](https://github.com/jonathanslenders/python-prompt-toolkit#getting-started) from project:

```
>>> from prompt_toolkit import prompt
>>> answer = prompt('Give me some input: ')
Give me some input: Hello World
>>> print(answer)
'Hello World'
>>> type(answer)
<class 'str'>
```

As `prompt` method return a string type, you could use `mock.return_value` to simulate the user integration with your app.